# Feeding data to Cytoscape and running

Tags: import, file-format, cytoscape

I am a Window programmer and would like to find a way to write a text data file containing basic node and edge information and properties (labels, properties, weights, etc.). It would not include graph coordinates.This file format should allow my program to call Cytoscape with the file name as the parameter so that Cytoscape will import the file and bring me to the Cytoscape GUI.

In terms of file format, the .cys file format (which is a zip file) is too complex and seems to contain too much information (unless one could create a stripped-down version with only basic information).

Is there another format that I can create that Cytoscape will recognize when passed on the program parameter string (like the .cys file format)?

Just as an example, the GEPHI software creates complex .gephi files, but one may also use the .gexf file format and associate this extension with the software. Other software will recognize instead script files and run a script passed to the program parameter string.

Any suggestion on an easy way to achieve this?

Thank,

Normand P.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!  There are several approaches, but the simplest file is a .sif file (simple interaction format), but Cytoscape can also read JSON (.cx or .cyjs) or various XML formats include GraphML and XGMML.  You didn't say what programming language you were using, but if you are writing in Python or R, there are packages that will allow you to push the data directly from those languages into Cytoscape (py4cytoscape and RCy3).

Comment: I did try double-clicking .sif file and while I can associate it with Cytoscape, it does not result in any data being loaded.  I also tried with GraphML and .cyjs files with the same results.  Nothing is loaded.  The application will either be in C++ or Delphi.

Comment: Hi Normand.  Just do a File->Import->Network from File to read in a .sif file.  Double-click is reserved for a Cytoscape session file.

Comment: What I was looking for was being able to push data and run the application. Simply exporting data will not do the trick.  We already do this for Gephi, NetDraw, Tableau, PowerBI, Stata, SPSS and many more.  We do export to those file formats as well, but users love when they can seamlessly run another tool with a single click on a button.  It seems such a small inconvenience, but I can tell you how people find it convenient when they can do all of this (finding the application, opening it, calling the importation routine, finding the data file, and importing it), in just one click.